# How I can solve Flutterflow firebase error?

Tags: flutter, firebase-authentication, flutterflow

When I tried to sign in using Email authentication  the firebase gave me this message

> an unknown error occurs :Firebase error (auth/invalid login credential))

I expect to login to the homepage if the entered information are correct.